# How to respond to git output from bashrc function?

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

I have to work with multiple git repo's and I want the ability to switch them all to a certain branch. So far with my limited knowledge of bash scripting I made this:

```
# Git switch all repos to a given branch.
switchall() {
    # Reset OPTIND so we can call this function multiple times.
    local OPTIND

    while getopts "b:" OPTION
        do
            case $OPTION in
                b)
                    echo "Switching all GIT repo's to: $OPTARG"
                    for d in ~/git/*/ 
                    do
                        ( cd $d && git checkout $OPTARG )
                    done
                    ;;
            esac
        done
}
```

But let's say I want to change all repo's to a certain branch but some of them don't have the specific branch I want to change to. I will get an error like this:

> error: pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.

This happens when I run:

```
switchall -b test
```

How can I catch the error message and suppress it or do something based on this specific error message that has been output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
( cd $d && git checkout $OPTARG 2>/dev/null )
if ! [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo things went wrong
fi
```

or even:

```
if ! ( cd $d && git checkout $OPTARG 2>/dev/null )
then
    echo things went wrong
fi
```

As it in `man bash` under `Special Parameters` section:

> ?      Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed
>   foreground pipeline.

Comment: That helps but is there also a way to respond to a specific message? Git could throw an error for a non-existing branch, unstaged changed, etc.

Comment: What do you men by `respond to a specific message`? If you still want `git` to print error messages just remove `2>/dev/null` part.

Comment: It needs to be a different response that matches certain errors, not just a generic error handler.